# How do I find all adjacent cells of a point in an n-dimensional grid?

Tags: python

Looking for adjacent - but not diagonally adjacent - tuples representing adjacent points of a point in an n-dimensional grid, where n varies. I have a tuple with n values, zero indexed and with each value being the point's location in a particular dimension. I also have another n-dimensional tuple representing the shape of the array.

Comment: I have trouble understanding your question, if I understand well you have data with n-dimension, why are you storing it in tuples instead of lists or numpy arrays?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, especially since there's no code in it to possibly clarify things—nonetheless, here's a guess. It defines an adjacent non-diagonal point as one whose distance-squared from the target tuple is exactly one.

I only tested it with some 2-dimensional non-arbitrary tuples—each one representing one of the 8 possible points surrounding one in the middle—to allow the results to could be easily checked. Regardless, it seems like it will also work when extended into higher dimensions with tuples composed of arbitrary values.

```
dim = 2
target = (1, 1)
tuples = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0),
          (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1),
          (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)]

adjacents = []
for tuple_ in tuples:
    if sum((target[k]-tuple_[k])**2 for k in range(dim)) == 1:  # Non-diagonal?
        adjacents.append(tuple_)

print(adjacents)  # -> [(1, 0), (0, 1), (2, 1), (1, 2)]
```

If my understanding was correct and this is correct, it could be rewritten and transformed into a "one-line" list comprehension.

Comment: How could this be updated to include diagonal cells as well?

Comment: @UzairA.: Change the `if` to just check for non-zero values to include them.